# submit form without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery

is it possible to submit this php form without refreshing the page. how would i go about setting a jquery code that can do this.

```
<?php
   if(!isset($_POST['sthis']))
    {
?>  
<div id="show">
<form method="post" action="">
something<input name="sthis" type="text" id="sthis" />
<input name="s" type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<?php
    }
     else
  {
    if(isset($_POST['sthis']))
    $sthis = $_POST['sthis'];
    if(empty($sthis)){echo 'put something in this box';}
    else echo 'ready';
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need ajax for that:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "your url here",
  data: "sthis=someValue",
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
  }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I like using AJAX for this, too, but I'm not sure this snippet provides enough to go on for intercepting the submit button, serializing the data from the form, and making the request to the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to use jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<form id="frmSample">
...
</form>

<div id="divResult"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $("#frmSample").submit(function(){
    //some code here

    $("#divResult").load("yourPhpCode.php", {variableName: value, variableName1: value});
  });
});
```

Check out [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).